# Присвоение нескольких значений одному полю таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Я пытаюсь сделать учёбную базу данных аптеки в phpMyAdmin. У меня есть таблица Product, в нёй есть поле sctucture (varchar), которое отвечает за состав продукта. Так-же у меня есть таблица ингрединтов, которая состоит из двух полей: id(int) и имя ингредиента(varchar). Мне нужно, чтобы в поле structure можно было указать сразу несолько ингредиентов. Я прбовал соединить structure и name через внешний ключ, но тогда получалось указать лишь один ингредиент. Каким образом мне надо связать таблицы, чтобы всё работало так, как я хочу. Буду очень благодарен за подробный ответ.

Comment: *Каким образом мне надо связать таблицы, чтобы всё работало так, как я хочу.* Пожалуйста, почитайте хоть что-нибудь по организации связей таблиц в базах данных. Особенно по организации связи типа много-ко-много.

Comment: Вам надо создать третью таблицу с id продукта и id ингредиента. соответственно на каждый продукт в ней столько записей, сколько ингредиентов в продукте